# Play framework core classes externalized in maven module

Tags: spring, maven, playframework, playframework-2.1

I'm starting a new project development and for now I'm quite pleased and interested by what Play! 2.1 offers. So I'd like to use it for the main website and end-user experience. However I wouldn't want to be dependent on Play for the rest of the project. I'd like to be able to write the admin module with say GWT anytime and so on.

So I'm thinking to use Play! as a kind of a front-end for my application which I'd write using Spring framework, Hibernate and Maven. I'll then package it as jar and add it to play as a SBT dependency.

The problem is this: how do I setup the development environment so I'll have 2 projects: one for the core classes using maven and the other for the website using play so that whenever I change code in the core project I won't have to build and redeploy the jar files to an internal maven repo from where play would be reading them. How can I achieve this kind of a setup?

BTW I'm using IntelliJ IDEA if this matters.